# What is this series called: $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x}{y^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x}{y^i} = x + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{x}{y^2}+...$$

And when does it converge?

The bottom part seems to produce $\frac{n}{n-1}$ from this wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series). If so, can it be combined to produce: $\frac{xn}{n-1}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you recognize it if you factor out $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) written in an "unusual way". It converges for any $y>1$ when you sum terms up to infinity. The sum of the $n$ first terms is, of course, always finite.

The sum can be calculated with the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) formula, according to which:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} xr^k = x \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Of course, you can take limits and see that, if $|r| < 1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} xr^k = \frac{x}{1-r}$$

In your particular case, you are just replacing $r$ for $\frac{1}{y}$, but the same applies

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x\frac{1}{y^k} = x \frac{1-\frac{1}{y^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{y}} \ \to \frac{x}{1-\frac{1}{y}}$$

In all of these cases, the $x$ could be simply taken out of the $\Sigma$ symbol, so the important part of the problem here is the geometric sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^k$$

Comment: Thanks! Followed through your geometric series link and came up with the same solution $\frac{x}{1-r}$ or $\frac{x}{1-\frac{1}{y}}$

Comment: @garbagecollector Hmmm... Were you interested about the sum up to $n$ of up to $\infty$ I was not sure so I wrote an answer that covered both

Comment: I was interested in the sum of up $n$, which is actually a $log_2 x$. In my case, ratio $0< r < 1$.

Comment: @garbagecollector Then no convergence issues apply. A sum of a finite number of terms always "converges"

Answer (score 1):

It is just a geometric series with common ratio $\frac 1 y$.For $x \neq 0$ it diverges if $0<|y|\leq 1$, converges for $|y|> 1$; for $x=0$ it converges for all $y$. Just use the formula for the sum of a geometric series too find the sum. [$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} xr^{k}=\frac x {1-r}$ if $|r|<1$].